# How to call salt-call state.highstate from a Python script?

Tags: python, salt-stack

Is it possible to call `salt-call state.highstate` (command) inside a python script and know when it’s done? (Masterless)

Comment: does the command return immediatly if you call it from the shell? or does it return when its done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Comment: yes, the salt-call command is used to run module functions locally on a minion and display the return of data.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Salt Client API](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/clients/) to achieve this.

When running masterless, you must use the `Caller` class, which provides the same interface as the `salt-call` command-line tool on the Minion.

```
import salt
caller = salt.client.Caller()
output = caller.function('state.highstate')
```

The output here is the full highstate result - there is no current way to run this asynchronously.

In order to to run highstate on a minion, use the `LocalClient` interface on the salt-master:

```
import salt
client = salt.client.LocalClient()
jid = client.cmd_async('minion-name', 'state.highstate')
```

The `jid` variable here is the Salt "job ID" for the highstate job. You can then query Salt for running jobs with:

```
client.cmd('minion-name', 'saltutil.running')
```

Which when run in a loop will enable you to check if the highstate has completed.

Comment: salt.client.LocalClient() seems it doesn't work with standalone minion (masterless)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you *might* need to write a [returner](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/returners/#writing-a-returner), that stores the result in a file or something

and call the command with

```
subprocess.check_output("salt-call state.highstate --returner=myReturner",shell=True)
#if the command blocks and does not return immediatly at this point it is finished

#if the command does not block you will have to check for the file that your returner creates until it exists
while not os.path.exists("my_returner_output.txt"):
     time.sleep(1)
print "OK COMMAND COMPLETE"
```